# Drive Api Quota

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a quota for drive api the dash sugestes 500k but is that a day or a month? can we ask for a quota increase?
Also can I use picker to select all google drive files from the external app?

Answer (score 1):

The quota in the APIs Console is per day, it should actually read "500,000 queries/day".
To ask for more, just click on the "Request more..." link next to it and fill the form.

You can use the Picker to display a list of the currently authenticated user's Drive files. Check the docs at https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open